How does one use border-image to set a color gradient to an element and still give it a border-radius?
I want to style a div but i want the div to have a border and I want the border to have two colors running from top left to bottom right. I tried using border-image, it worked but the border-radius won't work unless i remove the border-image. I wanted to know if there's anyway I can achieve this with any other method. If you check on the image, you'll see that it has a dashed border with  two different colors and i will really appreciate if someone could help me with how to achieve that.


.circle-border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #C74AD6, #A5502F) 1;
}
<div class="circle-border"></div>



This is the code I wrote.
